# Routine results in PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to run this code 24 times in order to find per hour value without copy and pasting the code 24 times.

```
<?php
  $result = mysql_query('SELECT date,SUM(value) AS value_sum FROM me Where WEEKDAY(date) >="6" AND HOUR(date)="0" '); 
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
  $h0= $row['value_sum'];
?>

<?php
  $result = mysql_query('SELECT date,SUM(value) AS value_sum FROM me Where WEEKDAY(date) >="6" AND HOUR(date)="1" '); 
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
  $h1= $row['value_sum'];
?>
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking? can you clarify.

Comment: I need to write this code 24 times to get the sum of the values per hour ($h0,$h1,,$h2...$h23). Is it any easier way to do it ?

Comment: Have you tried to use loops?

Comment: No :( , is what i am asking for. I didnt succed to use loops.

Comment: You can do that in SQL by adding `GROUP BY HOUR(date)`

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements, it really isn't hard.

Comment: So please have a look at my answer below - and maybe get some knowledge out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you modify your SQL statement in order to **get all tuples in one access, and then loop over the tuples** (in memory) **to sum up the value items**:

```
// Query the database
$result = mysql_query('SELECT date, value FROM me Where WEEKDAY(date) >="6" AND HOUR(date) >= "0" AND HOUR(date) < "24"');

// Sum values up
$h1 = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $h1 += $row['value'];
}
```

Executing an SQL statement - for several reasons - uses considerably more resources, and takes longer, than executing PHP code in a loop over all elements of an array.

This solution would execute one SQL query only instead of 24 queries.

(And, yes: use mysql**i** or PDO instead of mysql, which is deprecated)

Answer (score -1):

Try using a [for loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) and add your results into an array.

```
<?php
  $resultArray = array();
  for($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++;) {
     $result = mysql_query('SELECT date,SUM(value) AS value_sum FROM me Where WEEKDAY(date) >="6" AND HOUR(date)="' . $i . '" '); 
     $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
     resultArray[] = $row['value_sum'];
  }
?>
```